# WCF Metadata on separate port and not SSL

Tags: wcf, ssl, metadata

Pretty new to complex WCF configs and have looked around, but couldn't clearly answer this.
I'm looking for a yes this is possible and ideally a sample or no, this is not possible.

**Question:** 
Can you separate out the Metadata (WSDL) from a secure transport (SSL) service and make it plain old HTTP?

We have a WCF service that is using Transport security (SSL) for the service.
At this stage, during development we're using our own Certificates for the SSL, so we're a CA.

So the WSDL is exposed using

```
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

Under the service behaviours.

When you browse to the WSDL https://devserver:8010/MyService/?wsdl you get the usual, don't know the CA warning and just click IGNORE to continue on.

One of the problems I've got is that a proxy generation tool like JAX-WS just bails with a HTTP.403 Forbidden warning, even though I've put the CA certificate into the JDK/JRE keystore for cacerts.

So I was thinking, if I could separate out the Metadata then you could expose that on HTTP on a separate port and then there's no certificate issues for generating proxies.

So I tried marking the service metadata as follows:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://devserver:8011/MyService/" />
```

But this doesn't work as it's now mixing up the behaviour.

Perhaps I've missed something?
Perhaps this isn't possible?

And yes, to some extent it is moot, as a production machine WOULD have a trusted CA and therefore you won't get the certificate trust warnings.
However, it's now become a question of is this possible?

All help appreciated, thanks
Hadley

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify your MEX endpoint

[http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2006/11/09/WCF-Part-4-*3A00*-Make-your-service-visible-through-metadata.aspx](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2006/11/09/WCF-Part-4-_3A00_-Make-your-service-visible-through-metadata.aspx)

Note it will need a different binding configuration with security = None instead of transport.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for as you're following the standard practice of coupling the MEX with the service.
What I'm after is HOW or if it's possible to seperate the service and Metadata?
So imagine your Service has an endpoint defined as "https://devserver:8010/MyService" and a contract of "IMyService"
So the service is a transport secure one too!
How can I get my WSDL/Metadata on to a non-secure transport?

Answer (score 0):

Did some more trial and error and the end result which works is like this. This is shortened for brevity.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://devserver:8022/MyService/" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttp">
      <security mode="None">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviour" name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" 
    name="httpsEndpoint" contract="IMyService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://devserver:8020/MyService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```